# how can I use jquery to call the lightbox plugin when images are added to the dom after an ajax call?

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I am creating a form selection where images are added to the form after data is got from an ajax call. I want to call the lightbox() to show the larger form of these images - is this possible? The whole div that contains the image is built in a function and added to the dom with jquery?

```
$(".color_lightbox").live('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".color_lightbox").lightBox();
});
```

Do I need to prevent the default event?